# GNU make: dynamic targets from the content of a file which itself is a target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I wanted to do something like this:

```
target_list = target.list
targets = $(shell cat $(target_list)) # assume this yields a list of "*.o"
sources = $(subst .o,.c,$(targets))

all: $(target_list) $(targets)

$(target_list):
    some_command > $@

$(targets): %.o: %.c
```

However, `make` (actually `cat`) complains that `target.list` is not found when trying to define `$(targets)`. Is there a way of getting around this?

I understand I can use the following for the above example:

```
targets = $(shell some_command)
```

but the real word situation is more complex than a simple `cat` and `some_command` is expensive and has other uses late, so I'd really want to save its output.

Thanks.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem, if you go into a bit more detail about what `some_command` really does and why it's so expensive you might get a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `some_command` produces a space-separated list of object file names, this will work. (And if the format is something else, we can work around it.)

```
include target.list

all: $(targets)

$(targets): %.o: %.c

target.list:
    some_command | sed 's/^/targets:=/' > $@
```

When Make sees that it must `include target.list`, and that there is a rule for rebuilding that file, it will attempt to do so and then start over. And the rule for `target.list` prepends "targets:=" to the list, so the whole file can be pulled in as is.

Comment: @Beta Thanks! Didn't know about `include` before, which is exactly what I need.

Comment: [Official `include` directive documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html)